# Laravel save CSV file error

Tags: php, csv, laravel

I try to save CS with Laravel Excel.

```
Excel::create($filename, function($excel) {
            $excel->sheet('Excel sheet', function($sheet) {
                $sheet-> loadView('csv.csv')->with('data',$this -> pdfData);
                $sheet-> setOrientation('landscape');
       });
})->store('csv', public_path(''))
```

But i got error:

> ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 337: mkdir(): File exists
>   in Filesystem.php line 337
>   at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'mkdir(): File exists', '/var/www/dir/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php', '337', array('path' => '/var/www/dir/public', 'mode' => '511', 'recursive' => true, 'force' => false))

I think its permission error, but i dont know what i need to do.
I hope someone can help me.
Thanks

Comment: Its work on localhost, but not work in linux srv

Comment: create a folder in the public path and save the csv in that folder.. give 664 permission on that folder as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chown root:www-data public/` helps on me
Thanks all!